# Loading edge file to neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am new to neo4j. Can someone help me with loading script for the following edge file format?

File format with headers (all strings)
PRODUCT1,PRODUCT_PROPERTY1,PRODUCT2,PRODUCT_PROPERTY2

Following is my attempt to write loading script

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "products.csv" AS row
CREATE (p1:Product1)
SET p1 = row,
  p1.event = row.product_property1
CREATE (p2:Product2)
SET p2 = row,
  p2.event = row.product_property2
CREATE (p1)-[:depends]-(p2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///path/to/products.csv" AS row
MERGE (p1:Product {name: row.PRODUCT1})
SET p1.event = row.PRODUCT_PROPERTY1
MERGE (p2:Product {name: row.PRODUCT2})
SET p2.event = row.PRODUCT_PROPERTY2
CREATE (p1)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(p2)
```

- Be sure to specify the full path or url to the file
- Assuming the values in the `PRODUCT1` and `PRODUCT2` rows are some sort of unique name or id, you should use the [`MERGE` Cypher command](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-merge.html) to avoid possible duplicates. Also, you should create a [uniqueness constraint](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-constraints.html) on `Product(name)` to enforce this uniqueness: `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE`
- Be sure to specify a direction in the relationship you are creating